# Merge tab delimited text files into a single file

Tags: join, merge, tabs, delimited

What is the easiest method for joining/merging all files in a folder (tab delimited) into a single file? They all share a unique column (primary key). Actually, I only need to combine a certain column and link on this primary key, so the output file would contain a new column for each file. Ex:

```
KEY#  Ratio1  Ratio2  Ratio3
1     5.1     4.4     3.3
2     1.2     2.3     3.2
etc....
```

There are many other columns in each file that I don't need to combine in the output file, I just need these "ratio" columns linked by the unique key column.

I am running OS X Snow Leopard but have access to a few Linux machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually spent some time learning Perl and solved the issue on my own. I figured I'd share the source code if anyone has a similar problem to solve.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

#File: combine_all.pl
#Description: This program will combine the rates from all "gff" files in the current directory.

use Cwd; #provides current working directory related functions
my(@handles);

print "Process starting... Please wait this may take a few minutes...\n";

unlink"_combined.out"; #this will remove the file if it exists

for(<./*.gff>){
  @file = split("_",$_);
  push(@files, substr($file[0], 2));
  open($handles[@handles],$_);
}

open(OUTFILE,">_combined.out");

foreach (@files){
  print OUTFILE"$_" . "\t";
}

#print OUTFILE"\n";

my$continue=1;

while($continue){
  $continue=0;

  for my$op(@handles){
    if($_=readline($op)){
      my@col=split;
      if($col[8]) {
        $gibberish=0;
        $col[3]+=0;
        $key = $col[3];
        $col[5]+=0;  #otherwise you print nothing
        $col[5] = sprintf("%.2f", $col[5]);
        print OUTFILE"$col[5]\t";
        $continue=1;
      } else {
        $key = "\t";
        $continue=1;
        $gibberish=1;
      }
    }else{
      #do nothing
    }
  }
  if($continue != 0 && $gibberish != 1) {
    print OUTFILE"$key\n";
  } else {
    print OUTFILE"\n";
  }
}
undef@handles; #closes all files
close(OUTFILE);

print "Process Complete! The output file is located in the current directory with the filename: _combined.out\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

use the [join(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) utility

Comment: I was looking into using this utility but noticed that it is for combining two files, not all files in a folder. I'm not sure how I could leverage this tool without writing a good bit of code to make it work properly.